# End time exceeds epoch: ThreadPoolExecutor desires keepAliveTime <= max unix time

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Why does

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
   Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 
   Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
   Long.MAX_VALUE,
   TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
   new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
);
```

log "Note: end time exceeds epoch" on 32-bit systems?

---

*Backstory*. I observed weird log messages ("Note: end time exceeds epoch") when using the above code. The message produces several hits on Google ([one noting that](https://github.com/trietptm/Security-News/blob/master/Twitter/Zube/2017/2017_04_15.txt) the message "might be my favourite mysterious Android error"), but I didn't find a diagnosis. It wasn't causing a problem, but curiosity drove me to debug and my diagnosis appears below, I hope it saves another curious sole some time.

Answer (score 0):

Because `keepAliveTime = Long.MAX_VALUE` is greater than the maximum 32-bit Unix time (2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647). You can avoid log messages by replacing `Long.MAX_VALUE` with `2147483647` (preferably using constant `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, for good practice).

Comment: The maximum **"32-bit Unix time?"**  Can you justify that?  I would have assumed that Java used 64 bit time everywhere, and that the overflow was due to specifying seconds rather than millitseconds.

Comment: *preferably defined as a constant* -> `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @markspace I edited the question to clarify that the system is 32-bit.

Comment: But I mean, do you have the source code for the API somewhere that shows this?  Even on 32 bit systems Java has supported `long` since the beginning, I don't see why they wouldn't use that.

Comment: @markspace I have observed that no messages are logged when `2147483647`,  whereas they are for larger values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for the constructor, the time unit should be `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS` instead of `TimeUnit.SECONDS`.

> Using a value of Long.MAX_VALUE TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS effectively disables idle threads from ever terminating prior to shut down. By default, the keep-alive policy applies only when there are more than corePoolSizeThreads. But method allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean) can be used to apply this time-out policy to core threads as well, so long as the keepAliveTime value is non-zero.

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 
    Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
    Long.MAX_VALUE,
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, 
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
);
```

Also

> Long.MAX_VALUE = A constant holding the maximum value a long can have, 2^63-1.